# Positioning Images using css and HTML5

Tags: css, html

I am new to html5 and css from last few days i was playing well but now i am having a problem. Actually the images are not aligned properly, after three images the forth image goes to the second line but is not coming under the above image instead its coming under the menu/nav

i have used nav before article tag but when i use border to check how much area my article tag is containg the nav menu comes in it.. im kinda confused plz help..here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    </head>


        <body>
            <header>
                    <hgroup>
                    <h1>The Luxe Collection</h1>
                            <img src="graphics/header.jpg">
                            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4>
                    </hgroup>
            </header>
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Special Offers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Basket</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>

        </ul>
</nav>
            <article>
                        <header>
                            <h1>Hello Google user!     Welcome to Luxe Collections. What would you like to do?</h1>
                        </header>

                            <section>
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item1.jpg">
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item2.jpg">
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item3.jpg">
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item4.jpg">
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item5.jpg">
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item6.jpg">
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item7.jpg">
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item8.jpg">
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item9.jpg">
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item10.jpg">
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item11.jpg">
                            <img class="items" src="graphics/item12.jpg">
                            </section>

            </article>          

        </body>
</html>
```

here is my css which iam using for aligning these images *iam not posting css related to images only*

```
nav {
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    width:160px;

                }

nav ul {margin:0px;
         padding:0px;
        display:block;} 

nav ul li {margin-left:20px;
         padding:0px;
        list-style:none;
        padding-left:0px;
        line-height:2.5em;
        }

nav ul li a {display:block;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-family:"Kaushan Script";
        color:#CC123B;}

article {
        padding:10px;
        margin:0px;

          }

article header h1 {
                font-family:"Kaushan Script";
                  text-align:center;
                font-size:20px;
                color:#CC123B;
                    }
.items {
display:inline;
padding-right:10px;
margin:10px;
width:180px;
height:200px;
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Make a sample on jsbin.com or some similar service. It's a good practice to help people work on your issue.

Comment: You have some invalid HTML, `img` is self-closing and `hgroup` is not in the HTML specifications.

Comment: do you think only these are creating problem?? Yeah i think thre's somethink iam missing otherwise it shouldnot behave like that..

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle...

Comment: @user2989588 Validating your markup/css should be your first step in debugging what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @ cimmanon thanx for the advice, im going to validate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this (you could also apply it to the article):

```
section
{
  margin-left: 160px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, it solved the problem for now.. but i know there is problem somewhere in my html :) thanx again :)